# Travel and ketubah

Tags: halacha, travel, ketubah

We are planning to travel to Israel for the first time as a family, B"H. Do we need to bring our ketubah with us?

(I realize that this is probably a question for my Rav, but I am curious what the general answers might be.)

Comment: Where would you leave it otherwise? Somewhere safe?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that if you're moving there (or in the process of moving there and filling out paperwork), it helps to have a giant ton of documentation so the ketubah may be helpful. If you're just a family doing the tourist thing there for a few days, I can't see why a ketubah would be required, or even helpful. Best to leave it someplace self.

There are rumors of certain mikvahs in Israel that were concerned about single women trying to use them, and thus there was talk (I don't know if it became more than that) of demanding proof-of-marriage for a woman showing up at the mikvah. If you think this concern might be relevant, speak to a rabbi well-versed in the local Israeli issues -- or if you can't, contact www.yoatzot.org who will certainly be able to inform you of what mikvaot are in your area, and what experience to expect.

Comment: Thanks for the great information. I was more asking from the perspective of Halacha than whether or not it would be helpful to have. As far as I understand, the Halacha is that a couple should not be together if the woman does not have access to the kesubah. I was wondering if being ~7000 miles is considered not having access.

Comment: Also, I will note that we are planning to go for 5 weeks, although I would guess that even not having access for a day might be a problem, no?

Comment: @Chaim my understanding is as long as your wife knows where it is and has legal control over it, halachically you're fine. She has the peace of mind that if you were to decide to divorce her tomorrow, she could immediately call her lawyer in America who could retrieve the ketuba -- or fly back herself and get it if needed --  and it could then be used to demand a payment from you.